# How to store answers in tall and narrow MySQL table

Tags: mysql, data-structures

I'm designing a database to store questions and answers. I am planning on having 5 tables: quiz, question, userAnswer and multipleChoice

quiz:

```
quizID          (int)(primary key) Auto Increment
quizName        (varchar)
```

question:

```
questionID      (int)(primary key) Auto Increment
quizID          (Foreign Key)
question        (varchar)
questionType    (enum) textbox, multiple choice, int, date, decimal, email, ...
```

users:

```
userID          (int)(primary key) Auto Increment
firstname       (varchar)
surname         (varchar)
...
...
```

userAnswers:

```
questionID    (Foreign Key)
userID        (Foreign Key)
answerText
answerDec
answerDate
answerInt

PRIMARY KEY(questionID, userID)
```

multipleChoice

```
choiceID      (int)(primary key) Auto Increment
questionID    (Foreign Key)
choiceText    (varchar)
```

My problem lies with the answer table, some answers will be free form text, some decimals, and some integers (foreign keys)

How do I approach this? Do I have 4 columns, 1 for each type? If so, how do I efficiently select the correct one of 3 when retrieving the answers, I would like to do as much of the "heavy lifting" in SQL as I can, without having to use PHP to generate dynamic queries.

Comment: Maybe my english is too bad or I'm just a noob.. But what are "firing keys" and "heavy lifting" (in this context)?

Comment: You have 4 tables.  The first thing you do is to define the relationship between those tables.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Firing keys was an auto complete issue, should have been foreign keys. As for heavy lifting, it means hard work, I would like to use SQL to retrieve the data in 1 go, instead of getting the table type, then having a switch statement in PHP to choose which column for a second query. I will update my question with more information on how the tables are structured shortly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t need to search by the answers, then I’d recommend storing them in a JSON object or similar, and not bothering with seperate tables.

```
quiz | question   | answers     | multipleChoice
---- | ---------- | ----------- | --------------
1    | "Country?" | [           | true
     |            |   "France", |
     |            |   "Germany" |
     |            | ]           |
```

Comment: Json will not cut it.